# How to simulate data points from the following distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, simulation

I have the random variable $X\sim0.5Normal[2,2]+0.5Normal[20,2]$ and I am trying to use Mathematica to simulate, say, 500 points from this distribution. I briefly looked into Monte Carlo Simulation online, but I think they only use examples where the distribution is a "well-known" (i.e. Normal, Beta, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RandomVariate[
 MixtureDistribution[{.5, .5}, 
 NormalDistribution @@@ {{2, 2},{20, 2}}], 
 500]

Histogram[%, 30]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much!!!